# Store SQL variable from dropdown in PHP form

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm writing a piece of code for creating an invoice from several pieces of data.

Using a html form for inserting the data. The relevant line of code is,

```
<form method="post" action="">
<label id="icon" for="debtor_id_invoice">Debtor :</label><?php echo debtors_dropdown(); ?>
```

This calls the debtors_dropdown function which is located in the same file. The dropdown function is,

```
function debtors_dropdown() {
global $wpdb;

$sql_debtor = "SELECT `debtors_companyname`, `debtors_id`, `debtors_initials`, `debtors_surname` FROM `debtors` ORDER BY `debtors_surname`"; 
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql_debtor);

echo "<select name=debtor_invoice_id=''>Debtor</option>";
   foreach ($rows as $row){
    echo "<option value=>{$row->debtors_id} - {$row->debtors_surname}, {$row->debtors_initials}</option>";}
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Based on my form I use the variable,
 $debtor_id_invoice=$_POST['debtor_id_invoice'];

My whole point is,
I do get the dropdown list with correct values extracted from SQL. But I'm not quite sure how to store the selected value in the POST information. Because at the minute my variable stays empty. (I did a double check to echo the variable to see if it was really empty).

Can anybody point towards a solution to store the dropdown selection in the POST variable?
(Been googling but probably on the wrong values or something, I'm stuck :-S)

Thanks,
Grim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part creating the select looks wrong. Try:

```
echo '<select name="debtor_invoice_id">Debtor</option>';
   foreach ($rows as $row){
    echo '<option value="'.$row->debtors_id.'">'.$row->debtors_surname.', '.$row->debtors_initials.'</option>'; }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the contribution tobltobs See where you're going, just tried it. Same thing. The selected value was not stored in the form $_POST.

My doublecheck $debtor_id_invoice=$_POST['debtor_id_invoice']; returns no value.

Comment: Thanks all, solved it thanks to you. The code from tobltobs together with the corrected error seen by andre3wap & emipro works! Thanks all! Think my eyesight must have been troubled while looking at the code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think name of select is wrong in $_POST['debtor_id_invoice']. It is debtor_invoice_id

Comment: You're so true. Thanks for that changed it, but still no value returning.

Comment: Thats great. Please vote up or accept answer if you found it is useful

Answer (score 0):

you have the variables name incorrect.  In your form you have `name="debtor_invoice_id"`

However, in your `$_POST` you have; `$debtor_id_invoice=$_POST['debtor_id_invoice'];`

Your post should be `$debtor_invoice_id=$_POST['debtor_invoice_id'];`

Comment: You're so true. Thanks for that changed it, but still no value returning.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few problems in your code (the last one is what you where looking for):

- your missing the wordpress (mysql) table prefix `$wpdb->prefix` in your FROM part of your query. Wordpress uses this to prefix all the tables (and you should too).
- your html seems invalid: closing option tag without opening it before while loop `</option>`
- your html option tag value is invalid as well it should be: `value="{your data}"`

## fixup

```
function debtors_dropdown() {
global $wpdb;

$sql_debtor = "SELECT `debtors_companyname`, `debtors_id`, `debtors_initials`, `debtors_surname` 
FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."debtors` ORDER BY `debtors_surname`"; 
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql_debtor);

echo "<select name=debtor_invoice_id=''><option>Debtor</option>";
   foreach ($rows as $row){
    echo "<option value='{$row->debtors_id}'> {$row->debtors_surname}, {$row->debtors_initials}  </option>";}
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, fixed as well.